# Autodesk Forge from zero to hero: cannot connect to the remote server

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, forge

I follow the step at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uy6Cd6atCjU&t=1259s

However, I received the error:

This is the error when I click continue after successfully upload and translate dwf file

{System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Autodesk.Forge.Client.Configuration' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at Autodesk.Forge.Client.ApiClient..ctor()
   at Autodesk.Forge.Client.Configuration.setApiClientUsingDefault(ApiClient apiClient)
   at Autodesk.Forge.Client.Configuration..ctor(ApiClient apiClient, Dictionary`2 defaultHeader, String username, String password, String accessToken, Dictionary`2 apiKey, Dictionary`2 apiKeyPrefix, String tempFolderPath, String dateTimeFormat, Int32 timeout, String userAgent)
   at Autodesk.Forge.Client.Configuration..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Autodesk.Forge.TwoLeggedApi..ctor(Configuration configuration)
   at WebApplication1._default.d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\tozhang\Source\Repos\forgebasicsample-82\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\default.aspx.cs:line 33}

If I was not understanding wrong, this happened for not connecting to the remote server.
Actually, when I create an app at Autodesk, I provide https://www.google.co.nz/ as the callback url.  Do I need to register a callback url? Or it wont influence my app.

I have check many times to make sure the codes are correct and same as the video teach. But I still donot know whats problem.

Couldu pls help me on this? to check where is the erro from.

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `Update-Package –reinstall Newtonsoft.Json` ?

Comment: Yes, I had. But still donot work.